# reacting to users posts

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Regardless of my specific problem below, whats an effective way to respond multiple times to a users posts on the same page. So that on each progressive post on the page can capture new requests and display new information? *Forgive me if i'm not describing the problem correctly.*

I'm trying to build a page that reacts the the users posts. But i'm running into a :

> Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

I'm guessing because in my current solution:

```
@app.route('/survey', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])$                              
@contributer_permission.require(403)$  
def survey():
    organization_id = None
    survey_header_id = None
    survey_section_id = None

    organization_selected = None
    survey_header_selected = None
    survey_section_selected = None

    if request.method== 'POST':
        if not organization_id:
            organization_id = request.form['organization_id']
            organization_selected = Organization.query.get(organization_id)

        elif not survey_header_id:
            survey_header_id = request.form['survey_header_id']
            survey_header_selected = SurveyHeader.query.get(survey_header_id)
        elif not survey_section_id:
            pass
        else:
            pass

    return render_template('survey.html',
        organization_class = Organization,
        organization_selected = organization_selected,
        organization_id = organization_id,
        survey_header_id = survey_header_id,
        survey_header_selected = survey_header_selected,
        survey_section_id = survey_section_id,
        survey_section_selected = survey_section_selected)
```

once i receive the post carrying the survey_header_id. It reloops and

```
organization_id becomes none
```

Here is the the accompanying html/json

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class ="entries"> <!-- should be a DIV in your style! -->
    <form action="{{url_for('survey') }}" method="post" class="add-entry"/>
            <dl>
            {% if not organization_id %}
                {% for organization in organization_class.query.all() %}
                    <dt><input type="radio", name="organization_id",
                    value="{{ organization.id }}"/>{{ organization.name }}</dt>
                {% endfor %}
                <dt><input type ="submit", name="submit_organization"/>
            {% elif not survey_header_id %}
                <h1>{{ organization_selected.name }}</h1>
                {% for survey_header in organization_selected.survey_headers.all() %}
                    <dt><input type="radio", name="survey_header_id"
                    value="{{ survey_header.id }}"/>{{ survey_header.name }}
                {% endfor %}
                <dt><input type ="submit", name="submit_survey_header"/>
            {% elif not survey_section_id %}
                <p>hi</p>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            <dl>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What should i be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bad Request` is generally the result of accessing a parameter that doesn't exist, such as `request.form['organization_id']` when there is no element in the form with that name.

Your survey route will always attempt to retrieve `organization_id` from the form because you set it to `None`, and there's nothing to change that before it's tested.  On the second Post, your template does not create an `organization_id` element at all because the value was passed from the previous Post, so you see an error when `survey()` still attempts to retrieve it.

You need some way to pass your submitted values from one step to the next. For example, you could write them to hidden or disabled fields within the form so you can grab them and send them back out to the template after each Post, or store your state somewhere else like the `session`.